# I am unable to open any files in a directory as they all say they are corrupt

Tags: windows-8.1, file-management

All files in a subdirectory of OneDrive are unable to be opened and the programs report that they are corrupt or file type is not recognized.  When I look at them using a raw editor, I see the following in the header of all the files:

```
SafeGuard FileEncryption
Copyright 1998-2012 Sophos Group. All rights reserved. SafeGuard is a registered trademark of Sophos G
```

However, I have never encrypted the files.

Comment: Hi!  As-is, I'm not sure what you're asking us exactly?  Are you trying to decrypt them (probably not going to happen if you don't know the source), or are you trying to figure out how they became encrypted? if t's the latter, my guess is one of the place's you log in and use your OneDrive from has Sopho's FileEncryption turned on (i.e.: where you work). so perhaps it encrypted the files as they were downloaded, and then sync'd them back up to OneDrive, once encrypted. But that's just a guess, and I'm not sure we can offer you anything more than guesses based on what you've told us (so far).

Comment: Well something encrypted the files.  If you didn't encrypt the file, then you should restore them from a backup, or figure out what encrypted the file and decrypt them and upload them.

Comment: Thanks @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 !  My question was actually two:  1) How did the files become encrypted and 2)Is there any way to decrypt.  I wish I had more information into the mystery but I'm not aware of any my computers having sophos installed.

Comment: @russellkt - Check any and all machines that you have Sync your oneDrive too.  If you have file history on you might be able to restore the files that way.

Comment: @Ramhound Will do.  Does MS encrypt the files?

Comment: Based on the comments, I think I have come up with the issue.  My wife worked at a pharmaceutical company for a while and I bet she synced OneDrive to that computer which was encrypted.  Unfortunately, she now longer works for the Company and I don't have a backup :(  Hard lesson learned.

Comment: @russellkt - The files were clearly encrypted by a Sophos product called **SafeGuard** and not by Microsoft..